# Services Views module no longer maintaines. What are my options?

Tags: views, services, security

My site relies heavily on the Services and Services Views modules. The Services Views module is no longer being maintained and it has a security vulnerability in it. Could someone help me either identify what the security vulnerability is. Or point me to a decent alternative module?

Comment: There are 3 issues from people offering to maintain the module. The Drupal community does a great job of recognizing needs to be filled in my opinion. The only thing to do is to step up to maintain the module as a developer or sponsor as a company. This is one of the ways of contributing back. That said there are *three* issues already of people looking to maintain the module so the security issue will probably be resolved. Since the security vulnerability is not divulged (sometimes it usually is) it may be fairly significant so you need to analyze the risk of what func. it provides

Answer (score 1):

The Views Datasource's sub module called Views JSON is what I would recommend: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource

It's very similar to Services Views, except you just create a "JSON Data Document" Page Display for your View, and specify a Path at which the View can be accessed.